# Android button images gets pixelated?

Tags: android, button, resize, imageview, blur

I have few buttons in my app that i have applied circular png images on them but the edges gets pixelated, i don't know how to nine patch a circular image. If anybody knows a different way of doing it

Plzzz help

here is the code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerofbluefi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_Select_blue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_bluetooth" 
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b_Select_wifi"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_wifi" 
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

here is the screeshot:-

[image]

you can see the upper and lower portion is blured....

Comment: The images are stretched, try using different image resolutions, ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi. Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Also, try to not use weight or much worse, mixing weights. Weightsum is optional, you can apply weight for child views, but try to avoid it, use it when you can't find any other way. For ImageView try to set the source (src) and not the background. Android will auto-scale.

Comment: I suggest you start with a 96*96 px @ 480 dpi image (xxhdpi). put that in the drawable-xxhdpi folder and see it scaling DOWN. Now, it might look MUCH better. It will scale down to a 32*32 px image at 160 dpi (on mdpi screens)